# How can i get eval to function properly in IE?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
<select id="price_select"></select>
```

I have an event handler that invokes the following:

```
var selected_option = "one";
var option_one = "<option>Option Contents</option>";
document.getElementById('price_select').innerHTML = eval('option_' + selected_option);
```

Works just fine in Firefox but not in IE6.

Comment: Even though I have no problem with you doing whatever you want, know this: using eval() at all is generally frowned upon, especially in this instance where there are other ways to accomplish what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you do something like this instead?

```
var selected_option = "one";
var options = { "one": "<option>Option Contents</option>" };
document.getElementById('price_select').innerHTML = options[selected_option];
```

Comment: Why? That's an hash, which is like an associative array key => value.
I'm accessing the options element with key = selected_option, which will be "<option>Option Contents</option>" (which, btw, is a string and has no .text property) :)

Comment: I realised my mistake so I deleted my comment before your replied. Sorry for the trouble. :)

Answer (score 2):

Working off of what [marknt15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924135/how-can-i-get-eval-to-function-properly-in-ie/924153#924153) and [MartinodF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924135/how-can-i-get-eval-to-function-properly-in-ie/924142#924142) said, you should be able to use native DOM manipulation to do what you're trying to do without using `eval()`.

```
var selected_option = "one";
var options = { "one": {"value": "0", "text":"OptionContents"}  };
var e = document.createElement("option");

if(e.innerText) {// IE sets innerText like this
    e.innerText = options[selected_option].text;
} else { // W3C sets inner text like this
    e.childNodes[0].nodeValue = options[selected_option].text;
}

e.value = options[selected_option].value;

document.getElementById('price_select').appendChild(e);
```

You might want to consider using a full-featured JavaScript framework such as jQuery or Prototype to make things like this easier to handle though.

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML does not work in IE6 dropdowns because it is a bug.

eval() does work in IE 6

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
eval("var x= " + ('option_' + selected_option));
document.getElementById('price_select').innerHTML = x;
```